# Ecwid order - Create csv file of order export

Tags: php, arrays, json, csv

Having issue with my csv export because of how the json data is formated for an order.

```
{"vendorOrderNumber":"0137061","subtotal":38.95,"total":45.3,"email":"Donnar544@comcast.net","externalTransactionId":"5GS82233RB608634T","paymentModule":"PayPalStandard","paymentMethod":"PayPal / Credit Card","tax":0,"ipAddress":"73.130.161.92","couponDiscount":0,"paymentStatus":"PAID","paymentMessage":"Your order has been approved","fulfillmentStatus":"AWAITING_PROCESSING","orderNumber":7061,"refererUrl":"http://fvhardmerchandise.com/shop.html","volumeDiscount":0,"customerId":24198242,"membershipBasedDiscount":0,"totalAndMembershipBasedDiscount":0,"discount":0,"usdTotal":45.3,"globalReferer":"http://www.bing.com/search?q=wicked+tuna+hard+merchandise&qs=RI&pq=wicked+tuna+merchandise&sk=AS1&sc=5-23&sp=2&cvid=7A53D47A788E49C39B6DC837AE8D3E82&FORM=QBLH&ghc=1","createDate":"2016-01-08 01:10:18 +0000","updateDate":"2016-01-08 01:12:07 +0000","createTimestamp":1452215418,"updateTimestamp":1452215527,"items":[{"id":69376148,"productId":35290579,"categoryId":2455976,"price":14.95,"productPrice":14.95,"sku":"00275","quantity":1,"shortDescription":"Its finally here - an item lots of you have been waiting for! The Capt. Marciano Bobblehead in living color to keep yo...","tax":0,"shipping":3.0078947368421054,"quantityInStock":195,"name":"Capt. Marciano Bobblehead","isShippingRequired":true,"weight":0.9,"trackQuantity":true,"fixedShippingRateOnly":false,"imageUrl":"https://dpbfm6h358sh7.cloudfront.net/images/1039296/222187919.jpg","smallThumbnailUrl":"https://dpbfm6h358sh7.cloudfront.net/images/1039296/222187923.jpg","fixedShippingRate":0,"digital":false,"productAvailable":true,"couponApplied":false},{"id":69376149,"productId":35271535,"categoryId":2455976,"price":24,"productPrice":24,"sku":"00351","quantity":1,"shortDescription":"This slightly redesigned shirt from Hard Merchandise now has the CUDA brand knife logo on the back in their awesome whi...","tax":0,"shipping":3.3421052631578942,"quantityInStock":71,"name":"Tech Fabric Friends of Hard Merchandise Shirt","isShippingRequired":true,"weight":1,"trackQuantity":true,"fixedShippingRateOnly":false,"imageUrl":"https://dpbfm6h358sh7.cloudfront.net/images/1039296/313266743.jpg","smallThumbnailUrl":"https://dpbfm6h358sh7.cloudfront.net/images/1039296/313266748.jpg","fixedShippingRate":0,"digital":false,"productAvailable":true,"couponApplied":false,"selectedOptions":[{"name":"Size","value":"X-Large","valuesArray":["X-Large"],"type":"CHOICE"}]}],"billingPerson":{"name":"Dale E Read Sr","companyName":"","street":"544 Palm City Park","city":"Annville","countryCode":"US","countryName":"United States","postalCode":"17003","stateOrProvinceCode":"PA","stateOrProvinceName":"Pennsylvania","phone":"7176754357"},"shippingPerson":{"name":"Dale E Read Sr","companyName":"","street":"544 Palm City Park","city":"Annville","countryCode":"US","countryName":"United States","postalCode":"17003","stateOrProvinceCode":"PA","stateOrProvinceName":"Pennsylvania","phone":"7176754357"},"shippingOption":{"shippingCarrierName":"U.S.P.S.","shippingMethodName":"U.S.P.S. Priority Mail 2-Dayâ„¢","shippingRate":6.35,"estimatedTransitTime":"1-3"},"handlingFee":{"name":"Handling Fee","value":0,"description":""},"additionalInfo":{},"paymentParams":{},"hidden":false}]}
```

Issue comes in when the json shows the "items" details.
http://developers.ecwid.com/api-documentation#get-order-details

"items":[{"id":69376148,"productId":35290579,"categoryId":2455976,"price":14.95,......

csv file gets exported but when it hits this part of the json data it outputs the next few columns as "Array"  "Array"  etc...

**PHP File:**

```
    <?php
# An HTTP GET request example

$url = 'https://app.ecwid.com/api/v3/{STOREID}/orders?paymentStatus=PAID&fulfillmentStatus=AWAITING_PROCESSING&token={TOKEN}';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $data;

$json_obj = json_decode($data, true);
$fp = fopen('hardmerch_orders.csv', 'a');
    foreach ($json_obj['items'] as $items) {
         fputcsv($fp, $items);
    }
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Starting to build off of Alex Comments below but a bit lost on all the nested arrays. Not sure if I am on the right track at all.

```
    <?php
# An HTTP GET request example

$url = 'https://app.ecwid.com/api/v3/{STOREID}/orders?paymentStatus=PAID&fulfillmentStatus=AWAITING_PROCESSING&token={TOKEN}';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// echo $data;

$json_obj = json_decode($data, true);

//Ecwid Shopping Cart
//http://developers.ecwid.com/api-documentation#orders

$output = array();
foreach ($json_obj['items'] as $item) {
    $output['total'] = $item['total'];
    $output['count'] = $item['count'];
    $output['offset'] = $item['offset'];
    $output['limit'] = $item['limit'];
    $output['items'] = $item['items'];

    $output['vendorOrderNumber'] = $item['items'][0]['vendorOrderNumber'];
    $output['subtotal'] = $item['items'][0]['subtotal'];
    $output['total'] = $item['items'][0]['total'];
    $output['email'] = $item['items'][0]['email'];
    $output['externalTransactionId'] = $item['items'][0]['externalTransactionId'];
    $output['paymentModule'] = $item['items'][0]['paymentModule'];
    $output['paymentMethod'] = $item['items'][0]['paymentMethod'];
    $output['tax'] = $item['items'][0]['tax'];
    $output['ipAddress'] = $item['items'][0]['ipAddress'];
    $output['couponDiscount'] = $item['items'][0]['couponDiscount'];
    $output['paymentStatus'] = $item['items'][0]['paymentStatus'];
    $output['paymentMessage'] = $item['items'][0]['paymentMessage'];
    $output['fulfillmentStatus'] = $item['items'][0]['fulfillmentStatus'];
    $output['orderNumber'] = $item['items'][0]['orderNumber'];
    $output['refererUrl'] = $item['items'][0]['refererUrl'];
    $output['orderComments'] = $item['items'][0]['orderComments'];
    $output['volumeDiscount'] = $item['items'][0]['volumeDiscount'];
    $output['customerId'] = $item['items'][0]['customerId'];
    $output['membershipBasedDiscount'] = $item['items'][0]['membershipBasedDiscount'];
    $output['totalAndMembershipBasedDiscount'] = $item['items'][0]['totalAndMembershipBasedDiscount'];
    $output['discount'] = $item['items'][0]['discount'];
    $output['usdTotal'] = $item['items'][0]['usdTotal'];
    $output['globalReferer'] = $item['items'][0]['globalReferer'];
    $output['createDate'] = $item['items'][0]['createDate'];
    $output['updateDate'] = $item['items'][0]['updateDate'];
    $output['createTimestamp'] = $item['items'][0]['createTimestamp'];
    $output['updateTimestamp'] = $item['items'][0]['updateTimestamp'];
    $output['customerGroupId'] = $item['items'][0]['customerGroupId'];
    $output['customerGroup'] = $item['items'][0]['customerGroup'];

    //['discountCoupon']
        $output['name'] = $item['discountCoupon'][0]['name'];
        $output['code'] = $item['discountCoupon'][0]['code'];
        $output['discountType'] = $item['discountCoupon'][0]['discountType'];
        $output['status'] = $item['discountCoupon'][0]['status'];
        $output['discount'] = $item['discountCoupon'][0]['discount'];
        $output['launchDate'] = $item['discountCoupon'][0]['launchDate'];
        $output['usesLimit'] = $item['discountCoupon'][0]['usesLimit'];
        $output['repeatCustomerOnly'] = $item['discountCoupon'][0]['repeatCustomerOnly'];
        $output['creationDate'] = $item['discountCoupon'][0]['creationDate'];
        $output['orderCount'] = $item['discountCoupon'][0]['orderCount'];

    //['items'] 
        $output['id'] = $item['items'][0]['id'];
        $output['productId'] = $item['items'][0]['productId'];
        $output['categoryId'] = $item['items'][0]['categoryId'];
        $output['price'] = $item['items'][0]['price'];
        $output['productPrice'] = $item['items'][0]['productPrice'];
        $output['weight'] = $item['items'][0]['weight'];
        $output['sku'] = $item['items'][0]['sku'];
        $output['quantity'] = $item['items'][0]['quantity'];
        $output['shortDescription'] = $item['items'][0]['shortDescription'];
        $output['tax'] = $item['items'][0]['tax'];
        $output['shipping'] = $item['items'][0]['shipping'];
        $output['quantityInStock'] = $item['items'][0]['quantityInStock'];
        $output['name'] = $item['items'][0]['name'];
        $output['tangible'] = $item['items'][0]['tangible'];
        $output['trackQuantity'] = $item['items'][0]['trackQuantity'];
        $output['fixedShippingRateOnly'] = $item['items'][0]['fixedShippingRateOnly'];
        $output['imageUrl'] = $item['items'][0]['imageUrl'];
        $output['fixedShippingRate'] = $item['items'][0]['fixedShippingRate'];
        $output['digital'] = $item['items'][0]['digital'];
        $output['productAvailable'] = $item['items'][0]['productAvailable'];
        $output['couponApplied'] = $item['items'][0]['couponApplied'];

        //['files']
            $output['productFileId'] = $item['files'][0]['productFileId'];
            $output['maxDownloads'] = $item['files'][0]['maxDownloads'];
            $output['remainingDownloads'] = $item['files'][0]['remainingDownloads'];
            $output['expire'] = $item['files'][0]['expire'];
            $output['name'] = $item['files'][0]['name'];
            $output['description'] = $item['files'][0]['description'];
            $output['size'] = $item['files'][0]['size'];
            $output['adminUrl'] = $item['files'][0]['adminUrl'];
            $output['customerUrl'] = $item['files'][0]['customerUrl'];

        //['selectedOptions']
            $output['name'] = $item['selectedOptions'][0]['name'];
            $output['value'] = $item['selectedOptions'][0]['value'];
            $output['valuesArray'] = $item['selectedOptions'][0]['valuesArray'];
            $output['Big'] = $item['selectedOptions'][0]['Big'];
            $output['type'] = $item['selectedOptions'][0]['type'];
            // THERE ARE MORE SELECTED OPTIONS BUT I AM LOST AT HOW THEY SHOULD BE ADDED TO THE ARRAY.

            //['taxes']
                $output['name'] = $item['taxes'][0]['name'];
                $output['value'] = $item['taxes'][0]['value'];
                $output['total'] = $item['taxes'][0]['total'];
                $output['taxOnDiscountedSubtotal'] = $item['taxes'][0]['taxOnDiscountedSubtotal'];
                $output['taxOnShipping'] = $item['taxes'][0]['taxOnShipping'];

        //['billingPerson']
            $output['name'] = $item['billingPerson'][0]['name'];
            $output['companyName'] = $item['billingPerson'][0]['companyName'];
            $output['street'] = $item['billingPerson'][0]['street'];
            $output['city'] = $item['billingPerson'][0]['city'];
            $output['countryCode'] = $item['billingPerson'][0]['countryCode'];
            $output['countryName'] = $item['billingPerson'][0]['countryName'];
            $output['postalCode'] = $item['billingPerson'][0]['postalCode'];
            $output['stateOrProvinceCode'] = $item['billingPerson'][0]['stateOrProvinceCode'];
            $output['stateOrProvinceName'] = $item['billingPerson'][0]['stateOrProvinceName'];
            $output['phone'] = $item['billingPerson'][0]['phone'];

        //['shippingPerson']
            $output['name'] = $item['shippingPerson'][0]['name'];
            $output['companyName'] = $item['shippingPerson'][0]['companyName'];
            $output['street'] = $item['shippingPerson'][0]['street'];
            $output['city'] = $item['shippingPerson'][0]['city'];
            $output['countryCode'] = $item['shippingPerson'][0]['countryCode'];
            $output['countryName'] = $item['shippingPerson'][0]['countryName'];
            $output['postalCode'] = $item['shippingPerson'][0]['postalCode'];
            $output['stateOrProvinceCode'] = $item['shippingPerson'][0]['stateOrProvinceCode'];
            $output['stateOrProvinceName'] = $item['shippingPerson'][0]['stateOrProvinceName'];
            $output['phone'] = $item['shippingPerson'][0]['phone'];

        //['shippingOption']
            $output['shippingMethodName'] = $item['shippingOption'][0]['shippingMethodName'];
            $output['shippingRate'] = $item['shippingOption'][0]['shippingRate'];
            $output['estimatedTransitTime'] = $item['shippingOption'][0]['estimatedTransitTime'];

        //['handlingFee']
            $output['name'] = $item['handlingFee'][0]['name'];
            $output['value'] = $item['handlingFee'][0]['value'];
            $output['description'] = $item['handlingFee'][0]['description'];

        //['paymentParams']
            $output['Company name'] = $item['paymentParams'][0]['Company name'];
            $output['Job position'] = $item['paymentParams'][0]['Job position'];
            $output['PO number'] = $item['paymentParams'][0]['PO number'];
            //$output['"Buyer's full name'] = $item['paymentParams'][0]['Buyer's full name'];

        //['discountInfo']
            $output['value'] = $item['discountInfo'][0]['value'];
            $output['type'] = $item['discountInfo'][0]['type'];
            $output['base'] = $item['discountInfo'][0]['base'];
            $output['orderTotal'] = $item['discountInfo'][0]['orderTotal'];

        $output['hidden'] = $item['discountInfo'][0]['hidden'];     

}   

echo $output;

$fp = fopen('hardmerch_orders.csv', 'a');
foreach ($output as $line) {
    fputcsv($fp, $items);
}
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: the JSON string you posted is malformed, cannot possibly test it :)

Answer (score 0):

Taking the sample you provided here http://developers.ecwid.com/api-documentation#get-order-details as a valid JSON.

After `json_decode` if you inspect `$json_obj['items']` you will notice is an array of arrays.

The next loop cannot be safely converted to `csv` format since it contains further arrays

```
foreach ($json_obj['items'] as $item) {
    print_r($item);
}
```

This will output

```
...
[imageUrl] => http://app.ecwid.com/default-store/00006-sq.jpg
[fixedShippingRate] => 1
[digital] => 1
[productAvailable] => 1

[couponApplied] =>
[files] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [productFileId] => 7215101
                [maxDownloads] => 0
                [remainingDownloads] => 0
                [expire] => 2014-10-26 20:34:34 +0000
                [name] => myfile.jpg
                [description] => Sunflower
                [size] => 54492
                [adminUrl] => https://app.ecwid.com/api/v3/4870020/products/37208340/files/7215101?token=123123123
                [customerUrl] => http://mysuperstore.ecwid.com/download/4870020/a2678e7d1d1c557c804c37e4/myfile.jpg
            )

    )

[selectedOptions] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Size
                [value] => Big
                [valuesArray] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Big
                    )

                [type] => CHOICE
            )
    ...
```

Notice the inner arrays such as `files`,`selectedOptions` and more.
These will be printed as `Array` in your `csv`.

You need to manually build an array based on the data available.
Like this

```
$output = array();
foreach ($json_obj['items'] as $item) {
    $output['tax'] = $item['tax'];
    $output['imageUrl'] = $item['imageUrl'];

    $output['adminUrl'] = $item['files'][0]['adminUrl'];

    // rinse and repeat as needed
}
```

Then loop over it and write the `csv`

```
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'a');
foreach ($output as $line) {
    fputcsv($fp, $items);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thank you. I will test this out.. As for you comment above about malformed is that an issue with how I am getting the data with my curl command?

Comment: Also inside the json for orders there is a "items" column, is that going to mess up the decode of the json_obj['itesm'] as $item?

Comment: Regarding the first question I couldn't possibly say, since I can't test it myself

Comment: Second question: It shouldn't. You just have to manage all those nested arrays. The approach I'm suggesting is to cherry pick all the elements from the array and build your final array that you'll be using to generate the final csv from

Comment: this was from earlier that i am having issue with my json output looking different than the one directly supplied using just their https link in the browser.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679469/ecwid-order-json-output-issue

Comment: Do I just build out arrays for the nested objects, or do i need to include the json that is not nested in an array.  Also do i need to create a different array for each on, or all together as in my updated script above?